# Custom Bar Button with Image And Title

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I got the problem when i use Custom Bar button with image and title, I use below code

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
  button.titleEdgeInsets.left = 5
  button.setImage(buttonImg, for: .normal)
   button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
     button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.popVC), for: .touchUpInside)
   navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

And Here is the problem snippet. Text not show clearly

[image: The text not shows clearly]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    let backButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 30)
    backButton.setImage(buttonImg, for: .normal)
    backButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.popVC(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    backButton.sizeToFit()
    let backBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but now using this code title not appear.

Comment: Button width is not fixed. That is the maximum frame allowed.  backButton.sizeToFit() is used to set the button size according to its content.

Comment: I want to space between title and image, thats why i am using  `button.titleEdgeInsets.left = 5` and when i use this function button title not appear properly and without it every thing is working fine, So i just want to say that how can i set the space between title and button Thanks

Comment: You can use leading anf trailing spaces for that.

Comment: Example:   backButton.setTitle("     Your Title Goes Here", for: .normal)

Comment: WOW..Smart answer..I like it...And what about if i use two right bar button with image only no title, and i want to set space between them?

Comment: You can use Fixed/Flexible Space Bar Button Item for that.

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. Did you ever get this to work?